# How to make Hyper-V file share fast?

Tags: performance, hyper-v, shared-folders

On my developer notebook, I have a Hyper-V VM that is used as a 'DMZ' to connect to a certain VPN. Due to some restrictions and security concerns we don't want to install that proprietary VPN client on the host and have the host dial in directly to that VPN.

I shared a folder from my HOST, and the GUEST maps this folder as a network drive (D:/).

My problem: This connection is *extremely* slow.
Any file operation of the GUEST VM on the HOSTs data takes ages. A simple `git status` (which checks a lot of files) takes 5 to 10 minutes.

The question: What can I do to make the file access from my Hyper-V GUEST to the shared folder on the HOST acceptable fast?

Comment: What OSes are running on the Host and guest? Does file access to other file shares from the guest experience the same problem?

Comment: It's Windows 10 Pro both Host and Guest. And yes, Git on shared folders is slow everywhere.